# Internal forces not getting cancelled?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Consider a rope kept on a surface as shown. The ends of the rope are free.
[image]
The FBD of this rope given in the book is shown in the following diagram:
[image]
Now, consider the Tension forces at points P,Q and R,
[image]
, according to FBD ,the tension forces at these points aren't getting cancelled (vectorially adding upto zero). But we know, internal forces of a system must add upto zero. Where am I mistaken? (Here, I am considering the rope as a system)
Edit:[image]

Comment: If it is a rope, Then at curve points, There will be a small section curves of rope which will have a net tension direction, Net cancelling all Tensions vectorially,Even if it is a absolute sharp edge, it has to be attached by some hook like thread, Causing tensions in some other direction causing net tension vectorialy to be zero, For instance see how tensions of thread surrounding a pulley works

Comment: i believe the question is self answered , the direction of tensions at points P, Q and R would be just opposite to the direction of tensions shown in the FBD. Hence, getting cancelled. It took me a while to understand this.

Comment: How exactly, What are you thinking?

Comment: let me show it in the question itself

Comment: And why do you think that these direction cancel each other?

Comment: look at the edit i made, now combine the FBD and this diagram, eventually *Tb* would cancel (as they are in opposite direction)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151634/discussion-between-pinkaura-and-dheeraj-gujrathi).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there's a contradiction.  The conclusion to draw is that a perfect massless rope would not take up that shape under non-zero tension.  It would form some other shape.

This says that the massless rope is probably not the right model in this situation.  Maybe if there were some pulleys (which would apply the normal force required to balance the equations), but since I don't see anything, something else needs to be there.  Most likely the answer is that the rope has mass.  A rope with mass is permitted to have different tensions at different points.  Consider a heavy rope dangling vertically.  If you grab the loose end on the bottom, you can lift it easily, so the tension there is quite low.  But if you try to manipulate the rope from the top, you find there's huge tension there.

That rope with mass is now more difficult to calculate about, but you'll find it forms some natural curves to minimize potential energy.

Comment: it is not a massless rope